# html linking , relative path

Tags: html, css

i cant connect stylesheet to my html file, i cant inport image from my pc by realtive path. I have seen lot of questions here and i tried all the suggestions but i didnt found a solution, im 100% sure my syntax is right. Its wierd because i can inport images from url. It seems like my pc have some problem with relative paths, or it may be some wierd setting in my VS code. Can i get some advise to solve this, what should i try.

Here is some example...

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/style.css">
    </head>
    <body> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

i have tried all variations like href="style.css", href="./style.css"

Comment: The HTML is fine. The URL must be wrong. We have no way of telling what the URL should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid, but you might be mistaken in the location of the files your linking to. That would result in an invalid url.

Have a look at a folder structure as below. You've got a project folder name `project-example` this folder contains the `index.html` and the folders `templates` and `images`.

If you want to link in your `index.html` to the files in those folders the src or href would have to be something like `templates/style.css` or `images/image.png`.

[image: example of a folder structure]